# Searching from the end of a list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Many algorithms (like the algorithm for finding the next permutation of a list in lexicographical order) involve finding the index of the last element in a list. However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Mathematica that isn't awkward. The most straightforward approach uses [`LengthWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LengthWhile.html), but it means reversing the whole list, which is likely to be inefficient in cases where you know the element you want is near the end of the list and reversing the sense of the predicate:

```
findLastLengthWhile[list_, predicate_] :=
 (Length@list - LengthWhile[Reverse@list, ! predicate@# &]) /. (0 -> $Failed)
```

We could do an explicit, imperative loop with `Do`, but that winds up being a bit clunky, too. It would help if [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) would actually return from a function instead of the `Do` block, but it doesn't, so you might as well use [`Break`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html):

```
findLastDo[list_, pred_] :=
 Module[{k, result = $Failed},
  Do[
   If[pred@list[[k]], result = k; Break[]],
   {k, Length@list, 1, -1}];
  result]
```

Ultimately, I decided to iterate using tail-recursion, which means early termination is a little easier. Using the weird but useful `#0` notation that lets anonymous functions call themselves, this becomes:

```
findLastRecursive[list_, pred_] :=
 With[{
   step =
    Which[
      #1 == 0, $Failed,
      pred@list[[#1]], #1,
      True, #0[#1 - 1]] &},
  step[Length@list]]
```

All of this seems too hard, though. Does anyone see a better way?

**EDIT** to add: Of course, my preferred solution has a bug which means it's broken on long lists because of [`$IterationLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html).

```
In[107]:= findLastRecursive[Range[10000], # > 10000 &]
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. 
Out[107]= (* gack omitted *)
```

You can fix this with `Block`:

```
findLastRecursive[list_, pred_] :=
 Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
  With[{
    step =
     Which[
       #1 == 0, $Failed,
       pred@list[[#1]], #1,
       True, #0[#1 - 1]] &},
   step[Length@list]]]
```

`$IterationLimit` is not my favorite Mathematica feature.

Comment: If only lists were represented as double linked structures ...

Comment: are you sure your first line of code is correct? Unless I'm not understanding what it is supposed to do shouldn't the second `LengthWhile` be `LengthWhile[list//Reverse,  predicate@# &]`? So, adding a `Reverse` and removing the `!`?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Yes, you're right. I edited in a fix.

Comment: @Pillsy Regarding efficiency: generally (and as @belisarius demonstrated in his answer), structural operations are very fast in mma. So, while not reverting a list may be better asymptotically, you will probably need huge lists to really observe that, given that  list non-reversing solutions use mma evaluator which slows them down by a large constant factor w.r.t. those using `Reverse`.

Comment: @Pillsy sorry to try to reach you like this, but you need to confirm your email address for the Area 51 account before you come up on the commitment list. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/50888/pillsy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with `LengthWhile`-based solution. Also, if we want to reuse mma built-in list-traversing functions (as opposed to explicit loops or recursion), I don't see a way to avoid reverting the list. Here is a version that does that, but does not reverse the predicate:

```
Clear[findLastLengthWhile];
findLastLengthWhile[{}, _] = 0;
findLastLengthWhile[list_, predicate_] /; predicate[Last[list]] := Length[list];
findLastLengthWhile[list_, predicate_] :=
   Module[{l = Length[list]}, 
     Scan[If[predicate[#], Return[], l--] &, Reverse[list]]; l];
```

Whether or not it is simpler  I don't know. It is certainly less efficient than the one based on `LengthWhile`, particularly for packed arrays. Also, I use the convention of returning `0` when no element satisfying a condition is found, rather than `$Failed`, but this is just a personal preference.

**EDIT**

Here is a recursive version based on linked lists, which is somewhat more efficient:

```
ClearAll[linkedList, toLinkedList];
SetAttributes[linkedList, HoldAllComplete];
toLinkedList[data_List] := Fold[linkedList, linkedList[], data];

Clear[findLastRec];
findLastRec[list_, pred_] :=
  Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
     Module[{ll = toLinkedList[list], findLR},
       findLR[linkedList[]] := 0;
       findLR[linkedList[_, el_?pred], n_] := n;
       findLR[linkedList[ll_, _], n_] := findLR[ll, n - 1];
       findLR[ll, Length[list]]]]
```

Some benchmarks:

```
In[48]:= findLastRecursive[Range[300000],#<9000&]//Timing
Out[48]= {0.734,8999}

In[49]:= findLastRec[Range[300000],#<9000&]//Timing
Out[49]= {0.547,8999}
```

**EDIT 2**

If your list can be made a packed array (of whatever dimensions), then you can exploit  compilation to C for loop-based solutions. To avoid the compilation overhead, you can memoize the compiled function, like so:

```
Clear[findLastLW];
findLastLW[predicate_, signature_] := findLastLW[predicate, Verbatim[signature]] = 
   Block[{list},
       With[{sig = List@Prepend[signature, list]},
      Compile @@ Hold[
        sig,
        Module[{k, result = 0},
          Do[
            If[predicate@list[[k]], result = k; Break[]], 
            {k, Length@list, 1, -1}
          ];
          result], 
        CompilationTarget -> "C"]]]
```

The `Verbatim` part is necessary since in typical signatures like `{_Integer,1}`, `_Integer` will otherwise be interpreted as a pattern and the memoized definition won't match. Here is an example:

```
In[60]:= 
fn = findLastLW[#<9000&,{_Integer,1}];
fn[Range[300000]]//Timing

Out[61]= {0.016,8999}
```

**EDIT 3**

Here is a much more compact and faster version of recursive solution based on linked lists:

```
Clear[findLastRecAlt];
findLastRecAlt[{}, _] = 0;
findLastRecAlt[list_, pred_] :=
  Module[{lls, tag},
    Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity, linkedList},
       SetAttributes[linkedList, HoldAllComplete];
       lls = Fold[linkedList, linkedList[], list];
       ll : linkedList[_, el_?pred] := Throw[Depth[Unevaluated[ll]] - 2, tag];
       linkedList[ll_, _] := ll;
       Catch[lls, tag]/. linkedList[] :> 0]]
```

It is as fast as versions based on `Do` - loops, and twice faster than the original `findLastRecursive` (the relevant benchmark to be added soon - I can not do consistent (with previous) benchmarks being on a different machine at the moment). I think this is a good illustration of the fact that tail-recursive solutions in mma can be as efficient as procedural (uncompiled) ones.

Comment: +1. There are advantages to returning `0`, especially when dealing with `Compile`.

Comment: @Pillsy I usually reserve `$Failed` for functions doing something less algorithmic and predictable, like reading a file from disk, etc. But I think that this depends on the context in which you use it more than on the function itself. I can easily imagine that in some context returning `$Failed` for the problem in question will be more appropriate. I just don't think that general functions like this should do that - so in that case, I'd write a wrapper function converting `0` to `$Failed`.

Comment: @Pillsy I found an even faster recursive solution - please see my latest edit.

Answer (score 9):

Not really an answer, just a couple of variants on findLastDo.

(1) Actually Return can take an undocumented second argument telling what to return from.

```
In[74]:= findLastDo2[list_, pred_] := 
 Module[{k, result = $Failed}, 
  Do[If[pred@list[[k]], Return[k, Module]], {k, Length@list, 1, -1}];
  result]

In[75]:= findLastDo2[Range[25], # <= 22 &]
Out[75]= 22
```

(2) Better is to use Catch[...Throw...]

```
In[76]:= findLastDo3[list_, pred_] := 
 Catch[Module[{k, result = $Failed}, 
   Do[If[pred@list[[k]], Throw[k]], {k, Length@list, 1, -1}];
   result]]

In[77]:= findLastDo3[Range[25], # <= 22 &]
Out[77]= 22
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: You should docuument that second argument of `Return`. It makes it a lot more useful! :)

Comment: @Pillsy I filed a suggestion report for this.

Comment: +1 Any idea why this is undocumented? Any reasons to restrain ourselves from using it?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries No idea on that. Should be safe to use, as best I am aware. I use it.

Answer (score 7):

*For the adventurous...*

The following definitions define a wrapper expression `reversed[...]` that masquerades as a list object whose contents appear to be a reversed version of the wrapped list:

```
reversed[list_][[i_]] ^:= list[[-i]]
Take[reversed[list_], i_] ^:= Take[list, -i]
Length[reversed[list_]] ^:= Length[list]
Head[reversed[list_]] ^:= List
```

Sample use:

```
$list = Range[1000000];
Timing[LengthWhile[reversed[$list], # > 499500 &]]
(* {1.248, 500500} *)
```

Note that this method is *slower* than actually reversing the list...

```
Timing[LengthWhile[Reverse[$list], # > 499500 &]]
(* 0.468, 500500 *)
```

... but of course it uses much less memory.

I would not recommend this technique for general use as flaws in the masquerade can manifest themselves as subtle bugs.  Consider: what *other* functions need to implemented to make the simulation perfect?  The exhibited wrapper definitions are apparently good enough to fool `LengthWhile` and `TakeWhile` for simple cases, but other functions (particularly kernel built-ins) may not be so easily fooled.  Overriding `Head` seems particularly fraught with peril.

Notwithstanding these drawbacks, this impersonation technique can sometimes be useful in controlled circumstances.

Comment: I am not sure this uses less memory as written - the `$list` is anyway copied first by the system. You probably can fix this by making `reversed` `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`.

Comment: @Leonid I was unable to observe a memory spike that suggested that the array was being copied.  I used crude techniques like sprinkling `Print@MemoryInUse[]` calls in the `reversed` definitions and watching the virtual memory size as reported by external system tools.  Can you suggest a way to observe this copying?

Comment: @WReach It may be my misunderstanding of how mma treats expressions internally. I thought that whenever we use something like `a = Range[100];f[a]`,  first `a` gets copied into some internal heap space, which is then used by `f`. Apparently, mma seem to copy lazily :`In[66]:= MemoryInUse[] Out[66]= 11106272 In[67]:= a= Range[1000000]; In[68]:= MemoryInUse[] Out[68]= 15107248 In[69]:= b=a; In[70]:= MemoryInUse[] Out[70]= 15108536 In[71]:= b[[10]]=1;
MemoryInUse[] Out[72]= 19110352`. The real copying happened only when some destructive operation was performed on the list that prevented the ...

Comment: @WReach ... new variable to share a reference with the old one. In retrospect, this makes perfect sense, since in lots of cases copying is unnecessary. So, perhaps, I was wrong in this particular case, so please disregard my comment. On a different matter: the method you suggested is interesting, but it will probably not work for those built-in functions which bypass the main evaluator - a possibility that you anticipated. In other words, it has a chance to work only on functions implemented in the top-level mma (like `LengthWhile`), or at least so it looks to me. But very interesting, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternatives, two of which don't reverse the list:

```
findLastLengthWhile2[list_, predicate_] := 
 Length[list]-(Position[list//Reverse, _?(!predicate[#] &),1,1]/.{}->{{0}})[[1, 1]]+1

findLastLengthWhile3[list_, predicate_] := 
    Module[{lw = 0}, 
      Scan[If[predicate[#], lw++, lw = 0] &, list]; 
      Length[list] - lw
    ]

findLastLengthWhile4[list_, predicate_] := 
   Module[{a}, a = Split[list, predicate]; 
         Length[list] - If[predicate[a[[-1, 1]]], Length[a[[-1]]], 0]
   ]
```

Some timings (number 1 is Pillsy's first one) of finding the last run of 1's in an array of 100,000 1's in which a single zero is placed on various positions. Timings are the mean of 10 repeated meusurements:

[image]

Code used for timings:

```
Monitor[
 timings = Table[
   ri = ConstantArray[1, {100000}];
   ri[[daZero]] = 0;
   t1 = (a1 = findLastLengthWhile[ri, # == 1 &];) // Timing // First;
   t2 = (a2 = findLastLengthWhile2[ri, # == 1 &];) // Timing // First;
   t3 = (a3 = findLastLengthWhile3[ri, # == 1 &];) // Timing // First;
   t4 = (a4 = findLastLengthWhile4[ri, # == 1 &];) // Timing // First;
   {t1, t2, t3, t4},
   {daZero, {1000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 80000, 90000, 99000}}, {10}
   ], {daZero}
 ]

ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[{{1000, 10000, 20000, 50000, 80000, 90000,99000}, #}] & /@ 
     (Mean /@ timings // Transpose), 
   Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Zero position", "Time (s)", "", ""}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 14}, ImageSize -> 500
]
```

Comment: The problem with your list-nonreversing functions is that they traverse the list from the start, which (under assumptions that the result is likely to be found at the end) will likely be far less efficient than reversing the list and traversing that.

Comment: @Leonid True, if you happen to know that will be the case.

Comment: @Leonid From my timings it looks like if you don't have a clue the fourth method has the best overall performance.

Comment: These timings look a bit unexpected to me. Can you post the code you used?

Comment: @Leonid Added. I hope I didn't make a mistake. However, the timings don't look unexpected to me. Number 1 and 2 do a reverse then seek. Should do good with the zero at the end. Number 3 and 4 go through the whole list and should take a time roughly independent of the zero's position.

Comment: I should add an extra test to the 4th method to see whether the last sublists contains `True`s. But dinner's first.

Comment: I see now. Sorry, I thought you were timing the original solutions by Pillsy. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Timing `Reverse` for Strings and Reals

```
a = DictionaryLookup[__];
b = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
Timing[Short@Reverse@#] & /@ {a, b}

(*
 ->
{{0.016,         {Zyuganov,Zyrtec,zymurgy,zygotic,zygotes,...}},
 {3.40006*10^-15,{0.693684,0.327367,<<999997>>,0.414146}}}
*)
```

Comment: I get 0 for both timings. But what lesson should we learn from the above? That Reverse take longer for strings than for reals? Apparently so, as there are 10 times as much numbers as there are strings and the ByteCount of b is 8000168 and of a is 5639088.

Comment: @Sjoerd I learned that Reverse could represent a problem with really large string lists, but probably not for Reals. Besides, congrats for your tachyonic CPU.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: I think the lesson is that `RandomReal` returns a packed array, and operations on packed arrays are much faster than operations on normal lists. (And we could learn that the first call to Reverse takes slightly longer, but you probably thought to repeat the measurement a few times)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be:

```
findLastPatternMatching[{Longest[start___], f_, ___}, f_] := Length[{start}]+1

(* match this pattern if item not in list *)
findLastPatternMatching[_, _] := -1
```

but as it's based on pattern matching, it's way slower than the other solutions suggested.